# Date range picker error: initialDate must be on or before lastDate

Tags: android, flutter, dart

im trying to use a date range picker package i found online but i keep getting this error on initial start

heres my code

```
 onTap: () async {
      final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
          initialLastDate: (new DateTime.now()).add(new Duration(days: 7)),
          firstDate: new DateTime(2015),
          lastDate: new DateTime(2020)
      );
      if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
          print(picked);
      }
      print("Tapped on container"); 
    }
```

Error:

```
Failed assertion: line 1280 pos 10: '!initialLastDate.isAfter(lastDate)': initialDate must be on or before lastDate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion says that `initialLastDate` is after `lastDate`. This cannot be done. `DateTime(2020)` creates a `DateTime` at the beginning of the year 2020. At the time of writing we are far past this date. Change `lastDate` to after `initialLastDate`.

```dart
final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
  initialLastDate: (new DateTime.now()).add(new Duration(days: 7)),
  firstDate: new DateTime(2015),
  lastDate: new DateTime(2021)//Cannot be 2020
);
```